# How to toggle add/remove when adding html into a textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click on the button ADD, it should be adding all the html into the textarea, and works fine. However, If I click again I should be removing that from the text area. 
An idea maybe is by pushing the inserted html into an array?

```js
$('body').on('click', '.btn_video', function() {
  var $imageSelected = $(this).parent().parent().parent().prop('outerHTML');
  $('#usp-custom-5').val(function(_, currentValue) {
    return currentValue + $imageSelected
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
          <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/3fJjajItnEQ?rel=0&amp;modestbranding=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe></div><div class="caption">
          <p>Duration: <span class="video-time">31:54</span></p>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-block btn_video"><strong>ADD</strong></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
          <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/3fJjajItnEQ?rel=0&amp;modestbranding=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe></div><div class="caption">
          <p>Duration: <span class="video-time">31:54</span></p>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-block btn_video"><strong>ADD</strong></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<textarea name="usp-custom-5" id="usp-custom-5" data-required="false" placeholder="Example Input 5" data-richtext="false" class="usp-input usp-textarea usp-form-16" rows="5" cols="30" style="margin: 0px; height: 266px; width: 996px;"></textarea>
```

**[Here it is a Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tkk0kye7/24/)**.

```
$('body').on('click', '.btn_video', function() {
  var $imageSelected = $(this).parent().parent().parent().prop('outerHTML');
  $('#usp-custom-5').val(function(_, currentValue) {
    return currentValue + $imageSelected
  });
});
```

Comment: You should be removing or replacing the content of the textarea?

Comment: yes, if i click add the selected should be added to the textarea but if I click again on the button (the text would change into remove) it should be removing it from the textarea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tkk0kye7/27/)**.

You could use a helper class `selected` for this and add/remove it by click :

```
$('body').on('click', '.btn_video', function() {
  var content = "";

  if($(this).text()=="ADD")
  {
    $(this).text("REMOVE");
    $(this).parents(".thumbnail").parent().addClass('selected');
  }else{
    $(this).text("ADD");
    $(this).parents(".thumbnail").parent().removeClass('selected');
  }

  $('.selected').each(function(){
    content += $(this).prop('outerHTML');
  });

  $('#usp-custom-5').val(content);
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think you could reduce the code by just using the toggleClass instead!

Comment: @jmmontero there is the change text bit tho

Answer (score 0):

See if it's what you need:

```
return currentValue + $imageSelected
```

replace:

```
return $imageSelected
```

If you need to save the information before erasing, paste in an array:

```
var arr = [];
    $('body').on('click', '.btn_video', function() {
      var $imageSelected = $(this).parent().parent().parent().prop('outerHTML');
      $('#usp-custom-5').val(function(_, currentValue) {
        arr.push($imageSelected);
        return $imageSelected
      });
    });
```

Comment: that is only adding it once, but it is not removing it

Comment: Hey thanks, but I need to remove the selected from the textarea if I click again on its add button

Comment: Got it. I'll check it out here